# Jackcess: wrong charset for MSAccess database

Tags: java, excel, encryption, jackcess

I have a MS-Access database which has "encrypted" Strings in it. These look like that:
[image: encrypted strings]

However, I quickly noticed that the length of these Strings matches exactly the length of the plaintext (I know the plaintext). So with a bit of trying with Excel, I found out that if you use the `=CODE(<char>)`-function (so you get the character-code in the default charset, and `=CHAR(<number>)` viceversa) and xor this number with the character code of the letter the symbol should represent you **always** get the same result. Which means I just have to create an array with these values in java and voila. Excel example (on the right the mentioned "Array"):
[image: excel example decoding]
Example: ">>" has an index of (dec) 187, so 187xor253 yields 70 => "F"

Now, I use jackcess to access these values and the "decryption" is mostly fine but I sometimes get the wrong character out of strings. In Excel everything works just fine. Code with the best results:

```
public static final int[] DECRYPT_KEY = { 253, 203, 204, 217, 226, 205, 128, 201, 222, 183, 58, 217, 230, 201, 183, 211, 158, 203, 167, 213, 35, 33, 201, 123, 186, 247 };

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));


    Database db = DatabaseBuilder.open(new File("/home/***/TM.db"));                
    Table table = db.getTable("personal");

    for (Row row : table)
    {
        String vorname = row.getString("vorname");
        byte[] vornameArr = vorname.getBytes("cp1252");
        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < vornameArr.length; i1++)
        {               
            vornameArr[i1] = (byte) ((vornameArr[i1] & 0xff) ^ DECRYPT_KEY[i1]);
        } 

        System.out.println(new String(vornameArr, "cp1252"));
    }
}
```

But as I said, some characters are still wrong, in Excel however everything is fine. When I print out the number which `getBytes("cp1272")` gives, it is completely different to the Excel one.

Do you have any ideas, what I could be doing wrong and why java gives sometimes such different values than Excel? What would be a better approach? I already tried all combinations of charsets, some worked where others failed but then had other wrong results.

Comment: hmmm....strange. Just for the heck of it, try "windows-1252". "cp1252" is the Canonical Name used for java.io API and java.lang API and "windows-1253" is the Canonical Name used for java.nio API.

Comment: No, sadly it doesn't help. The name "Fadima" shown above results in "FadiÝa". And this is the only one, all others are fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So thanks to @Gord Thompson and the website he suggested (fileformat.info) I finally found an answer: Sometimes characters look similar, and for some reason in the database the "higher" ones are preferred (such as unicode character 402 and 131). My java code expected everything to have the lower value, as excel provided it. So, if the code is higher than 255 it needs to be substituted by a lower value. For some reason, `getBytes("cp1252")` will always return that lower value, however `toCharArray()` and `getBytes("UTF-16LE")` will return the higher, correct value (Compare: [fileformat 192](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/192/charset_support.htm))

So my code is like this now and works perfectly:

```
String vorname = row.getString("vorname");
char[] vornameArr = vorname.toCharArray();          
for (int i = 0; i < vornameArr.length; i++)
{
    if (vornameArr[i] > 255)
    {
        vornameArr[i] = (char) (String.valueOf(vornameArr[i]).getBytes("cp1252")[0] & 0xff);
    }

    vornameArr[i] = (char) (vornameArr[i] ^ DECRYPT_KEY[i]);
}

System.out.println(String.valueOf(vornameArr));
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post your findings. To clarify: It's not that `getBytes("cp1252")` returns "[a] lower value" for a given character, it simply returns the single-byte value for that character - "LATIN SMALL LETTER F WITH HOOK" - *in the Windows-1252 character set*. It illustrates the difference between the *Unicode code point* for that character (0x0192, decimal 402) and the corresponding *byte value* in Windows-1252 (0x83, decimal 131).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to recreate your issue by hacking a database file with the byte values in your question. The line

```java
byte[] vornameArr = vorname.getBytes("cp1252");
```

tries to convert the `vorname` characters to cp1252 bytes, but there is no cp1252 character corresponding to U+008F (decimal 143, [SINGLE SHIFT THREE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/8f/index.htm)), so Java converts that character to a question mark (0x3F). Therefore, your decoding step is decoding 0x3F instead of 0x8F, which is why you get "FadiÝa" instead of "Fadima".

I was able to get the correct result by replacing the single line above with

```java
byte[] doubleBytes = vorname.getBytes("UTF-16LE");  // 187 0 170 0 168 0 ...
byte[] vornameArr = new byte[doubleBytes.length / 2];
for (int i = 0; i < vornameArr.length; i++) {
    vornameArr[i] = doubleBytes[i * 2];  // remove nulls
}
```

and then running the `vornameArr` bytes through your decoding loop. (You could also apply the decoding transformation in the above loop if you preferred.)

Comment: Thank you very much! This brought me a step further. Unfortunately, all of the other names are having problems now. For example "Thomas" is
`[-87, 0, -93, 0, -93, 0, -76, 0, -110, 1, -66, 0] (array before)
[84, 104, 111, 109, 112, 115] (array after)
Thomps`

Comment: What are the raw numbers, as would appear in the spreadsheet you showed in your question?

Comment: For "Thomas" it would be `169, 163, 163, 180, 131, 190` which should turn into `84, 104, 111, 109, 97, 115`, so the only difference is the 97 <=> 112.
"Thomas" ist the first name you see in the first picture, starting with the copyright-sign

Comment: I just tried it and it worked for me: I got "Thomas" (97), not "Thomps" (112).

Comment: I have found one thing: Excel gives me symbols which look similar, but are not quite the same. For example the "f" thing in Thomas: According to Excel it is a `NO BREAK HERE`. If I copy it into google and search it, it suddenly becomes a `LATIN SMALL LETTER F WITH HOOK`.

I try and get a database for you, so it get's a bit easier.